# App starts in Debug Mode, but fails to load in Release mode

Tags: android, xamarin

This is a big problem, since I uploaded this version to google play. 
I start the app in debug mode, and it works. I release it, and it wont load.

What could I be doing? Do you need any other info?

Comment: So the deployment step fails completely? You should remove the app from the phone and try again.

Comment: yes. i did all that. deleted every possible instance of either xamarin and the app itself. i just get a white screen, no error message and after about 20 seconds of nothing, visual studio ends the process without any warning and the app just closes.

Comment: Check the output tab for errors. Since you're running on release mode, Visual Studio won't catch the exceptions.

Comment: thanks mate. I got it to work fortunatelly!

Comment: Np, good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thankfully -

in the options under build i had to disable "use mono runtime". that fixed the issue: THANK GOD